# MySQL Framework

Tags: mysql, frameworks

I am looking for a MySQL Framework.  I have a database ready containing 100's of tables.  I just want to attach a front-end to this database using which one can edit, modify and delete the data in the database. I am not willing to write php code for this work as I have some time-constraint. So does a solution for this exist? In my basic research I stumbled upon Xataface. How is it? Are there any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: I use PhpMyAdmin. But that is not the solution i m looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There are some other as well:

- [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)
- [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)
- [SQLyog and MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/)

For database modeling:

- [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) which has 30-day free trial. You can download it from [here](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php). List of features available: http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_matrix.php

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). It has many features and it more user friendly

The main PhpMyAdmin features are as follows:

- User-friendly web interface;
- Support for most MySQL functions like browse, drop, create, copy and
  alter databases, tables, views, fields and indexes, execute MySQL
  queries, manage stored procedures and functions;
- Import data from CSV and SQL files;
- Export data to various formats: CSV, SQL, XML, PDF, ISO/IEC 26300 -
  OpenDocument Text and Spreadsheet, Word, Excel, LATEX and others;
- Searching globally in a database or a subset of it;
- And much more.

Answer (score 0):

For an user interface, you can try phpmyadmin as a web based and a lot of desktop applications depending upon your operating systems.
If you are looking at a programming framework for the user, then cakephp or rails are an excellent option - you would have to need extra tables for storing metadata though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a GUI to work with MySQL databases, you can try [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Try Trial or free Express edition. Here it is a list of [features](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/features.html).